# RxJS replay last message with uniquekey

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have a stream of events of multiple types. On a new subscription, I'd like to repeat the latest event for each type (the only one), and then continue with any new events.

Say I have an event for: `DoorStateChange(door_id, new_state)`, `LockStateChange(lock_id, new_state)`, `Booted(boot_time)`.

From each event, I can create a string for deduplication, `DoorStateChange/${door_id}`, etc.

So in case I received the events:

```
Booted(129048124093)
DoorStateChange(door1, Opened)
DoorStateChange(door2, Closed)
DoorStateChange(door1, Closed)
LockStateChange(door1, Locked)
LockStateChange(door2, Locked)
LockStateChange(door1, Opened)
```

If I get a new subscriber, I'd like for it to receive the following immediately, and then all further events:

```
Booted(129048124093)
DoorStateChange(door2, Closed)
DoorStateChange(door1, Closed)
LockStateChange(door2, Locked)
LockStateChange(door1, Opened)
```

How can this be achieved? I'd need shareReplay, with some kind of filter, so old values are overwritten... Or better yet, specifying the number of messages to replay of each type / identifier.

EDIT:

I got as far as this:

```
const { interval, of, timeout, ReplaySubject } = Rx;
const { groupBy, mergeMap, share, switchMap, delay, shareReplay  } = RxOperators;
 

const int = interval(300).pipe(share());


const obs = int.pipe(
  share(),
  groupBy(x => x % 3, undefined, undefined, () => new ReplaySubject(1)),
  mergeMap(g => g.pipe(shareReplay(1))),
);



const allEvents = obs;
const subscribedLater = of(1).pipe(delay(2350),switchMap(() => obs));


of(allEvents, subscribedLater)
```

https://rxviz.com/examples/custom

But the question remains on how to repeat the last message from each inner observable created in the `groupBy`, because neither using a `ReplaySubject`, nor piping to a `shareReplay` does not seem to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In RxJS can I set up a ReplaySubject (or similar) that replays all the most recent messages with a unique name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75801398/in-rxjs-can-i-set-up-a-replaysubject-or-similar-that-replays-all-the-most-rece)

Comment: The problem being solved is the same, but the solution is to remember all messages, and then just filter out the last one. My solution is a bit better because although it instantiates a ReplaySubject for each group, it will only keep the latest one in memory. Still suboptimal though.

Comment: The solution doesn't remember all messages. Only the last one of each type

Comment: I was looking at the wrong answer. Yes, you are right, but it won't continue to stream each element after the subscription. Actually I believe it will exhibit a wierd behaviour, that after each incoming message happening after the subscription, it will keep repeating each remembered message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wound up using groupBy with a ReplaySubject and mergeAll. Not sure about the efficiency of it though, since each group would instantiate a ReplaySubject.

```
const { interval, of, timeout, ReplaySubject } = Rx;
const { groupBy, mergeAll, share, switchMap, delay, shareReplay  } = RxOperators;
 

const int = interval(300).pipe(share());


const obs = int.pipe(
  groupBy(x => x % 3, undefined, undefined, () => new ReplaySubject(1)),
  shareReplay(), // Replay observables for each group, each replaying one message
  mergeAll(),
);



const allEvents = obs;
const subscribedLater = of(1).pipe(delay(2150),switchMap(() => obs));


of(allEvents, subscribedLater)
```